# It's too slow to sync to Google Drive using GoodSync

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using GoodSync to sync the 2.06TB files on my external hard drive to Google Drive. It has been around 4 days, but there is not much progress.
GoodSync is still making directories on Google Drive, and the speed is 4Kb / sec. The estimated time remaining is roughly 100,000 hours.

When I count the number of directories through the command `$ find ./ -type d | wc -l`, it says 47651. And the number of files through the command `$ find ./ -type f | wc -l` is 709671.

I'm using IMAC late 2012.
The specifications are as follows.

version : 10.14.1.

Processor : 2.7GHz intel core i5

Memory : 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3

The results of Internet speed measurement by fast.com are as follows

Current Internet speed : 16Mbps

Upload speed : 32Mbps

Is Sync so slow because creating a directory on Google Drive is slow? Or is there something else wrong? How would I do appropriate things if I try another?